# Skiprows arguments in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I was looking in the Python documentation, skiprows specifically, if it was possible to use skiprows to skip from row 1 to 5 and after 70 to row 101, but it doesn't show me how to do it that way. Does anyone know how to do it? Do I necessarily need to create a `for` loop to do this?

Comment: Are you referring to the `pandas.read_csv` function?

Comment: `pandas.read_excel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `read_excel` documentation lacks a good description of what `skiprows` can do. The `read_csv` is better:

```
skiprows : list-like, int or callable, optional
        Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int)
        at the start of the file.
    
        If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row
        indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False otherwise.
        An example of a valid callable argument would be ``lambda x: x in [0, 2]``.
```

In your case, you could just make a list of the rows to skip or use ranges (or even a lambda). Your case is a bit complicated because you you want to skip multiple ranges. Assuming you want to skip 1-5 inclusive, counting from 0, you could

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', skiprows=list(range(1,6)) + list(range(70,102)))
```

Or

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', skiprows=lambda val: val not in range(1,6) and val not in range(70,102))
```